# Blenderguru's Coffee tutorial: Coffee does not reflect correct in Viewport/Rendering

Tags: rendering, physics, lighting, glass, reflection

UPDATE:
So resetting default preferences helped. But I checked the preferences file (not readable with editor). I then screenshot evry settings tab and compared with factory settings. There was no change then 1 addon: NodeWrangler. Deinstalling Nodewrangler didnt help, first the factory reset.
So there must be a different option somehwere else which is also saved in the userpref.blend .
Perhaps anyone else could imagine?

---

I followed BlenderGurus Beginner Tutorial, and in [Part 4, Level 3: Realistic Liquid - Blender Beginner Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdWUjEMzDhg) I have following problem.
In Viewport (Image right side) you can see the coffee shines more dark through the glass and has dark-reddish reflection on the plate/ground.
In the Rendering the glass looks very greyish and there is a highlight reflection on the plate/ground as if there is some lightsource or coffee won't be rendered correct.
The liquid is sized to fit between the both sides of the glass and I followed all material settings and couldn't find out where the problem is. Could you help me here?

Best Regards
Sören

[image: Text]

It should look like this in Render: (from tutorial)
[image: Text]

Update:
After the Answer of @Jachym:
Still same false behaviour for me:
[image: Text]

Blender File:
[image]

Comment: No I am not sure. :) I did just everything like in the tuts. Could you give me a hint how to do ?

Comment: are you using eevee or cycles?

Comment: I am using cycles

Comment: I added a pic of the tut how it should look in rendering also (like in viewport). Not like at my setting, different shadows in viewport/rendering, and rendering looks unnaturally

Comment: Hi again, @Jachym Michal I uploaded the file to my question. Sorry I missed that before ;)

Answer (score 1):

I checked your file and everything seems to be working fine.
With such low samples, Denoiser can introduce some artifacts, so perhaps that's what happened.

*Viewport (64 samples)*
[image]

*Render (128 samples)*
[image]

*Render (128 samples) + Denoise Node*
[image]

Comment: Surely I have settings 64/128 and denoising node, but I downloaded the file and tried it again. still different result as you may see in the screenshot I added in the post. Some problem with settings?

Comment: UPDATE: @Jachym Michal : If I download a new Blender Portable it renders correctly. So must be something with settings, but can you think of what it could be ?

Comment: Hey :). This means it's probably something in your Blender Preferences. You can load *factory preferences*, and see if that helps. No idea what it could be though, sorry :).

Comment: Perhaps someone else could imagien what setting it could be ?